# Would the proper way to followup the word 'reminder' be 'to' or 'for'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was writing out a message for my followers, and in the middle of the sentence I wrote "reminder to everyone," and then I paused and thought to myself that I don't know if that's the proper way to word it. I was just wondering if the proper way to word it would be "reminder *to* everyone" or "reminder *for* everyone."

Comment: see also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110269/what-preposition-should-be-used-with-reminder-in-this-phrase

Answer (score 1):

Either "to" or "for" are acceptable.  I slightly prefer "for", as it suggests that everyone is to benefit from the reminder.  But "to" is equally acceptable.

Google searches find lot of examples of both phrases.